# program using the rand () function

Tags: c, random, scanf, modulo

I want to make a simple program in which the `rand()` function generates a random number out of 1,2,3 and the user is asked to predict the number. if the user predicts the number correctly then he wins otherwise he looses.
Here's the program-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int game;
    int i;
    int x;

    printf("enter the expected value(0,1,2)");
    scanf("%d\n",&x);
    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        game=(rand()%2) + 1

        if(x==game){
            printf("you win!");
        }

        else{
            printf("you loose!");
        }
    } return 0;

}
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I think that `game=(rand()%2) + 1` needs to be `game=(rand()%3)` because you use 0,1,2 in the first `printf`

Comment: @CoolGuy Right, added this to my answer. :-)

Comment: Why do you need the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

**Point 1:**

```
    scanf("%d\n",&x);
```

should be

```
    scanf("%d",&x);
```

**Point 2:**

```
for(i=0;i<1;i++)
```

this for loop is practically *useless*. It only iterates one. either use a longer counter, or get rid of the loop.

**Point 3:**

It's better to provide a unique seed to your PRNG. You may want to use [`srand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) and [`time(NULL)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) in your function to provide that seed.

**Point 4:**

```
game=(rand()%2) + 1
```

should be

```
game = rand() % 3; // the ; maybe a typo in your case
                ^
                |
          %3 generates either of (0,1,2)
```

**Point 5:**

When you use `%` with `rand()`, be aware of [modulo bias issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/2173917).

---

Note:

1. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. Always initialize your local variables. Good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `\n` from your scanf()

`scanf("%d\n",&x);` to

```
scanf("%d",&x);
```

and place a semicolon(;) after `game=(rand()%2) + 1;`
it works.

Your for loop is not required here.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask any question but I guess it is "Why my rand() function doesn't work?"

You need to add these lines

```
#include <time.h>
```

and the random initialization at the beginning of the main function:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Which should give:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int game;
    int i;
    int x;

    printf("enter the expected value(0,1,2)");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        game=(rand()%2) + 1;

        if(x==game){
            printf("you win!");
        }

        else{
            printf("you loose!");
        }
    } return 0;

}
```

Edit: there are other problems as Sourav said